# Port based virtual hosts in CentOS 5.5 / Webmin

Tags: linux, centos, port, centos5

I am trying to setup virtual hosts in the respect that everything is in the /var/www/html/ root folder however, I am trying to setup folders within that and then setup port related url's.

- myserverip - Would get the local intranet
- myserverip:8181 - Would get my personal website
- myserverip:8080 - Would get the intranet blog etc

I tried setting these up through webmin, however they just won't resolve. I disabled the Linux Firewall, as it's on a local intranet and will NEVER have remote access / public access from the internet. Our local intranet is completely locked down.

Does anyone have any suggestions with this as I have got to the point where I am just clutching at straws :(

Thanks for your time, if I manage to get any further, I will edit this post so that you have further information. Please understand I am a server newbie :(.

---

**Below is what is inside the httpd.conf file**

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080
Listen 8081

NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:8080
NameVirtualHost *:8081

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName SERVERIPHERE
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerName SERVERIPHERE
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example2
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8081>
        ServerName SERVERIPHERE
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example3
</VirtualHost>
```

**And this is the error returned**

```
Starting httpd: (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:8081
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8081
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

Comment: Does the IP address you are using match the one shown by ifconfig? If so, can you ping it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be selinux in enforcing mode, httpd is not allowed to listen to port 8081, check /var/log/audit/audit.log

Comment: It doesn't want to work on any other port either :/

Only seem to work on the default :80 port and :8080...

Comment: Good point - type "getenforce" and see if it says enforcing

Comment: Yes it's Enforcing, so how would I go about stopping that?

Comment: No worries, I actually went to the box and changed it via the gui... Will let you know shortly IF it has fixed the issue :) Thanks

Comment: Yep... That fixed it guys... Thank you so much... I can't 1 up at the minute due to newbie status.